# hp Laserjet printer M477-toner stuck

Tags: printer

We installed the replacement Laserjet toner for the HP M477 printer the salesman picked out for us, but it was the wrong cartridge, now it's stuck and we can't pull out the cartridge rack to remove the toner. It was supposed to be the 410A-black, but he sold us the 201X-black. I tried searching youtube videos, but none showed how to disassemble the printer to open the cartridge rack...Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you upload a photo of the printer with the service hatch opened since it would elicit a greater community response in addition to helping the community better glean your question.

Comment: I tried to upload a picture, but it transferred with a rotated view...If there's an easier way to upload it, I haven't found it yet!